# Magento Admin Category tree

Tags: magento

How do i show the Category tree which is in the Admin menu in the admin section somewhere on other page [but admin side].

Also I dont want to generate tree using custom js. Just need to use the default functions.

Comment: Why was this Downvoted? If you cant answer move on.. If you dont understand letme know...

Comment: I am also searching for this for months but still not getting it

Answer (score 6):

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_categories')->setTemplate('catalog/product/edit/categories.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Comment: There is a error when I try to get the tree using the above code.




Call to a member function getCategoryIds() on a non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Categories.php on line 75.......





Please help.